# Multistage docker build for Django

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-multi-stage-build

I am dockerizing my Django application with docker multi-stage build. Now am facing an issue with dependencies

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster AS base
WORKDIR /app
RUN python -m venv venv
ENV PATH="/app/venv:$PATH"
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt \
    && pip install gunicorn
COPY entrypoint.sh .
COPY . .

FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
WORKDIR /app
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
COPY --from=base /app /app/
ENV PATH="/app/venv:$PATH"
ENTRYPOINT sh entrypoint.sh
```

When running the container it raises import error.

**ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?**

Comment: the second FROM should be FROM base

Answer (score 0):

I went to the same situation few month ago and it was a conflict between 2 packages, so django was not installed during the pip install.

You can add on your docker build command the '--progress=plain' option and see if everything is ok, during the docker build :

- $ docker build --no-cache --progress=plain -t my_service_name .
  Baptiste.

Answer (score 0):

here is a working multistage docker build for django.

```
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /opt/webapp/

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
# copy requirements.txt
COPY ./requirements.txt /opt/webapp/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir

# runner stage
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster AS runner

ARG SECRET_KEY
ARG DEBUG

WORKDIR /opt/webapp
RUN groupadd -r django \
  && useradd -d /opt/webapp -r -g django django \
  && chown django:django -R /opt/webapp
USER django

COPY --from=builder /opt/venv /opt/venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"

COPY --chown=django:django . /opt/webapp/

# run the server
CMD gunicorn conf.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```